# Indexing Tf-Idf values

Tags: information-retrieval, tf-idf, inverted-index

If I want to use Tf-Idf approach in a project, and I have an inverted index, Can I add the Tf-Idf values to the indexer ?! "from scientific point of view" ..

If yes, is it correct way! since we need to re-indexing the corpus when we add any new document.